# Multi-Role based user login in Android(java)

Tags: java, android

I have multiple roles for user login, I have successfully implemented if one user has only one role but the problem is if a user have more than one role then how can I implement that.

Thanks and Regards
Prabhat Pandit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is: You can ask from a user at runtime that by which role he/she want to login.

Second is: At the login time let the user select from drop down that by which role he/she want to login.

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on your login response. Let's assume the user login using his/her credentials then the role of the user should be in response and accordingly, you can navigate to the respective screen. I have mentioned below the Login response.

For Admin user:
{
"user_role":"admin"
}

For normal user:
{
"User_login":"user"
}

Else you have to create your UI more dynamic you have to deal with multiple ternary or if-else conditions. each view on screen will depend on login response.

**NOTE: I'm assuming you are getting Role type in API response.**